# Sharing an instance object across classes

Tags: vb.net

is it good practice to use a shared instance object across classes.
or is there any effective way...
I am planning to implement it in some framework pl suggest any better approach

for example.

```
public Class Globalinfo
    public shared class1Obj As Class1 = new Class1
    public shared class2Obj As Class2 = new Class2
    public shared class3Obj As Class3 = new Class3
End Class

public Class Class1
    'Private data
    'private method
    Public Function Switchstatus() As Boolean

    return True

    End Function     
End Class

public Class Class2
    'Private data
    'private method
    'turn switch 
    Public Function TurnSwitch() As Boolean

    'check status of switch
    if Globalinfo.class1Obj.Switchstatus = False

    End If

    return True    
End Class

public Class Class3
    'Private data
    'private method
    Public Function light() As Boolean

    'check status of switch

    if Globalinfo.class1Obj.Switchstatus = True
    'makelight on

    End If    
End Class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you ware looking for some `Static Class` instead for `public shared Instance` of the class. Static class have the following behaviors. credits goes to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

- A static class cannot be instantiated.
- you can access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.
- A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to get or set any internal instance fields.